# STM32F4 CubeMX SysTick timer rate

Tags: microcontroller, c, stm32f4, stm32cubemx, cortex-m4

I am using CubeMX to generate initialization code for STM32F407 MCU. I wonder where  can i see the SysTick timer rate in CubeMX or its generated code?

I am using 8 MHz external crystal and set SYSCLK and HCLK to 168 MHz. What will be the rate of SysTick timer?

Comment: Probably 1 KHz.  Find the active ISR, possibly from a listing file and see how much it adds.  If you have suspicions it might be wrong, toggle a GPIO in the ISR, or generate output every N seconds in the foreground and user a terminal program which can timestamp.

Comment: Search the vendor code for something like `HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000U)` which would setup a 1 KHz rate... if the clock is what the code thinks it is.

Comment: If you use HAL libraries it's always 1 KHz. I'm not sure if you can change or see it in CubeMX. Also some functions from HAL (for eg. HAL_Delay) are based on this timer so you must be very careful if you want to change it's rate. Chris is right about `HAL_SYSTICK_Config`

Comment: I am using external osc. 8M Hz and have set the system clock at 168 MHz for STM32F407 using CubeMX but in the code file 'system_stm32f4xx.c' i see it as follow: uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 16000000; Is it some bug in CubeMX code generation that I am not getting the correct value here?

Comment: As far as I know, the SystemCoreClock  variable is updated during initialization to match the correct frequency.